# Mirror Maker not making topic automantically

Tags: apache-kafka

I am setting a mirror maker between 2 clusters of kafka .

Kafka Version: `kafka_2.11-2.1.0`

My `server.properties` has `auto.create.topics.enable=true` .

I am running mirror maker on my target cluster .

But the new topics don't get created automatically when source cluster adds a topic . I have to end up creating them manually .  And even after creating manually , the records from source cluster don't get populated in this new topic , until or unless i don't restart my mirror maker . Once restarted , it starts replicating immediately post insert of data on source .

Mirror Maker command

```
./kafka-mirror-maker.sh --consumer.config consumer.properties  --producer.config producer.properties  --whitelist '.*'  --num.streams 2
```

Consumer.properties

```
bootstrap.servers=!source_host_name_with_port!
group.id=consumer_replicator_group
client.id=mirror_maker_consumer
exclude.internal.topics=true
```

Producer.properties

```
bootstrap.servers=!destination_host_name_with_port!
acks=1
batch.size=100
client.id=mirror_maker_producer
```

Any ideas please.

Answer (score 0):

It's documented on the Kafka website to create the topics on the destination first. If you don't, then you get the default partition and replication counts on the destination cluster (which often do not match the source topic)

Comment: I agree , and i am fine with it , to be created with default configurations, but that's not happening for me . The target cluster doesn't even come to know that new topic is created . As mentioned in my problem statement , even after creating the topic manually , i have to restart mirror maker , so that it starts syncing data .

Comment: I don't think the whitelist is periodically checked to create topics on the destination. Only to consume data.